# UltraWinGrid: How to refresh displayed data

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

i am new to infragistics and to winGrids

I have SQL database with the following table

```
Costumers
[ID][Name]
```

In addition , i have UserControl which has winGrid and add\remove buttons.

When the UserControll becomes, active winGrid datasource is bounded to the table

```
winGrd.DataSource = Tables.Costumers;
```

When user wants to add\remove data from costumers table he clicks the relevant button.
The table is changed accordingly but the displayed data in the grid is **not changed**.
I used

```
winGrd.Refresh();
```

but it does no effect

what is the way to do this, Code examples are welcome

thanks

---Edited ----
Adding code:

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        //...

        DB.DataProxy.AddCostumer(txtType.Text);
        winGrd.Refresh();

        //...
}
```

AddCostumer method eventually calls for the following method that updates the costumer table

```
public void AddCostumer(string type)
{
        Costumers.InsertOnSubmit(new InsertOnSubmit{ Name = name});
}
```

Comment: You should show the code used to update the database. I suspect that you are using a direct access to the database without updating the DataTable `Costumers`

Comment: i have DAL layer which uses linq, the table is update !! When i close the UserControll and create it again, the data that is displayed is updated.

Comment: Maybe I have to be clearer. The Costumers DataTable is a disconnected object and updating the table on the database doesn't change the DataTable object who is binded to the Grid. I suspect this is the problem. You say that the user clicks a button to delete a row from the grid. That's the code I wish to see - buttonRemove_click or buttonAdd_Click

Comment: Hey, you probably right, i've updated the question with the code which inserts the costumer to the costumers table. How do i 'connect' Costumers table.

Answer (score 3):

If your `DataTable` is being updated, the `UltraGrid` should be showing those changes for you. What you could try is to call

```
ultraGrid1.Rows.Refresh(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RefreshRow.ReloadData);
```

or

```
ultraGrid1.Rows.Refresh(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RefreshRow.RefreshDisplay);
```

Comment: These don't have any effect unless you have updated the data in the DataTable that the grid is bound to.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but, as from [MSDN documentation on InsertOnSubmit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx)

`The added entity will not appear in query results from this table until after SubmitChanges has been called.`

So, perhaps, if you want the result appear immediately in the Costomers entity and then in the WinGrid, you should call, in the code above the SubmitChanges()

```
public void AddCostumer(string name) 
{ 
    Costumers.InsertOnSubmit(new Costumers() { Name = name}); 

    // Submit the change to the database.
    try
    {
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       // message to the user???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you executed the add/remove command, re-pull the data from database and redo the binding. Set the DataGridView.DataSource to null before all that, just in case; you wouldn't want to display wrong data if the connection or any other database-related process fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are setting a DataSource that doesn't implements IBindableList which UltraGrid uses for automatically update data it changes.
You could try refreshing it manually setting DataSource to null and resetting DataSource again when you need to show new info.